# To give usercontrol in src of iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, modalpopupextender

i have a `ModalPopupExtender`  like,

```
<ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeClientView" runat="server" TargetControlID="lblClientName" PopupControlID="frmMaodalPopup" OkControlID="closeBtn"></ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

and an `iframe` like

```
<iframe id="frmMaodalPopup" runat="server" src="/DashboardUserControls/ClientInformation.ascx" width="700px" height="400px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and a `LinkButton`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch1" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnClick="lnkSearch_Click" Text="Client Name"></asp:LinkButton>
```

When i click the LinkButton i want the iframe to popup which src is a UserControl ClientInformation.ascx. But when i click the button the iframe pop up, but it is not able to load the usercontrol. Kindly point out where i'm making the mistake

Comment: Well I suggest, before clicking the button check if the iframe is show ing the page with the control. This way you can make sure if its loading properly or not. And later you can check with event (button click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The user control can not run by himself**.

You need to make an aspx page, place this control inside that page, and load that page on the iframe.

Comment: just out of curosity, if i load the user control inside an asp panel and make the panel popup it works perfectly. so which one will be better, popping up the panel that contain the user control or popping up the iframe which contain an aspx page?

Comment: @Rain Its depend on what this pop up do, how time its take to load, how often you call it, if you make post back and you like to stay on page. If for example this dialog, needs to stay there after the post back, use iframe. If not and its fast to load, then you may avoid to load one more page.... its up to you to decide what is better for your page. The iframe is load it on call, the other way is to load it in advanced.